# Is Yahari Ore no Seishun Love Comedy wa Machigatteiru. Zoku a remake?

Tags: oregairu

I've been watching this anime, then while I was watching it, I had no idea what's really going on.

Aftering watch the first season, I started the second one (Episode 1-5), I realized that one or more scenes in *Zoku* is the same with the first season.
(What I remembered the most is the PSP scene)

Comment: Can you be more specific on what's the same? It's unclear what you are referring to...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, [*Yahari Ore no Seishun Love Comedy wa Machigatteiru. Zoku*](http://myanimelist.net/anime/23847/Yahari_Ore_no_Seishun_Love_Comedy_wa_Machigatteiru._Zoku) is simply the second season of the show [*Oregairu*](http://myanimelist.net/anime/14813/Yahari_Ore_no_Seishun_Love_Comedy_wa_Machigatteiru./), and not a remake of the first.

While both are adapted from the original [manga](http://myanimelist.net/manga/40171/Yahari_Ore_no_Seishun_Love_Comedy_wa_Machigatteiru.), the current two seasons of the anime are chronologically ordered, following directly on from one another.
This is clear after comparing the episode synopses of both [season 1](http://myanimelist.net/anime/14813/Yahari_Ore_no_Seishun_Love_Comedy_wa_Machigatteiru./episode) and [season 2](http://myanimelist.net/anime/23847/Yahari_Ore_no_Seishun_Love_Comedy_wa_Machigatteiru._Zoku/episode) on their corresponding MyAnimeList pages.

There may well be some similarities in the two seasons, as shows often provide throwbacks or other references to earlier works, but since the plot itself continues on, this isn't enough to classify it as a remake.

Comment: One dead giveaway is the matching content between the ending of the first season and the beginning of the second season, and the atmosphere carried over from the first season.

Comment: Oregairu actually started as a light novel; the anime and manga are both based on that. See https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/My_Teen_Romantic_Comedy_SNAFU.